# Mac equivalent of Windows + Period

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, special-characters, emoji

On Windows, pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Period</kbd> opens a menu that allows you to type Emoji, a few multicharacter emoticons, and characters from a list of symbols that's similar to the list used by MS Word.  Is there an easily accessible way to type such symbols on a Mac?

Comment: duplicate: [Automatically pop up shortcuts for emoji and symbols in Google Chrome on MacBook](https://superuser.com/q/1744192/241386)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can !! :-)

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>...