# Automatically pop up shortcuts for emoji and symbols in Google Chrome on MacBook

Tags: google-chrome, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook

Sometimes I want to pop up emoji or symbols, but it's cumbersome because I need to right-click and then click “Emoji & Symbols.”

Is there some shortcut that automatically pops up emoji and symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system default keyboard shortcut is  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Space</kbd>

If you want to change it, see [Ask Different - Changing Emoji Shortcut](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/230382/85275)

Comment: No worries - btw, the styles used in the answer are 'accepted usage'. We don't put + between key commands. The shortened URL to the AD question tells the system it's a  'public shared' URL, not an internal link.

Comment: @MyCar I have no idea where Tetsujin gets the idea “We don't put + between key commands.” Many people use the + command and that is even commonly seen in many non Stack Exchange sites like [this one](https://www.reed.edu/cis/help/diacritics.html). If Tetsujin prefers this style, that is their personal choice and not a site-wide policy… Unless Tetsujin can provide evidence to back up this claim.

Comment: As per Stack Exchange policy, [I have mentioned you in a thread](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14787/167207) on this “We don't put + between key commands.” claim in Meta.